# What do Abraham and Levi each like?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

Abraham and Levi are two friends who like many of the same things, but sometimes their preferences can diverge. Given the examples below, determine what governs their curious differences of opinion.

- While Abraham enjoys **DRAMA**, only Levi likes **THEATER**.
- Abraham prefers **ART**, but Levi chooses **TECHNOLOGY**.
- Abraham likes an **ICONOCLAST**; Levi would rather an **IDEOLOGUE**.
- Abraham fancies a **HOMEOPATH** whereas Levi would pick an **ASTROLOGER**.
- Abraham favors **PERIODS**. (Levi prefers **PARENTHESES**.) <sup>1</sup>
- Abraham is a fan of **IRONY** and **SARCASM**, but **SATIRE** and **FARCE** are Levi’s inclination.
- Although Abraham is partial to **SCIENCE**, only Levi appreciates **ZOOLOGY**, **CHEMISTRY**, and **ECOLOGY**.
- **PARABOLAS**, **LOGARITHMS**, and **ASYMPTOTES** all interest Abraham, but Levi is the **MATH** lover.

(Note that Abraham and Levi are both quite fussy, and as such, there are many things which neither friend likes.)

Here are the example items as CSV, which Levi was kind enough to alphabetize for me:

```
art, asymptote, drama, homeopath, iconoclast, irony, logarithm, parabola, period, sarcasm, science
astrologer, chemistry, ecology, farce, ideologue, math, parentheses, technology, theater, satire, zoology
```

---

<sup>1. In some spoilery comments below @greysaff's answer, some users have argued that Levi also likes the period…though I would argue Abraham likes it approximately 5 times as much.</sup>

---

**Hint 1:**

> There are many subjects Abraham and Levi both enjoy, such as history, geography, and electricity (though only Abraham likes magnetism). They also both appreciate numerals, cycles, and graphs.

**Hint 2** *(this is probably a bigger hint, so view with care!)*:

> Some of Abraham’s favorite books are *Angels & Demons*, *Don Quixote*, and the dialogues of Socrates and Plato. He also likes reading horror and poetry (his favorite poet is Sappho). Levi enjoys reading biographies, mythologies, allegories, and the Bible.

**Hint 3** *(this probably won't help much with the solve, but these terrible puns popped into my head and so now you've all got to suffer with me)*:

> If each friend were to post the things he likes as a conventional [*What is a Word™*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) puzzle in the style of [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), Abraham might call the things he likes **Frozen Words™** and Levi might call his **Julian Words™**.

Comment: Your CSV list has ASYMPTOTE where the main text has ASYMPTOTES. Are both correct?

Comment: Pluralization is irrelevant in all cases.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli Constipation? No, but it's possible he might have diuresis.

Comment: ^ Since the comment this was in reply to has been (rightly) removed, I will clarify that my response was regarding Abraham.

Comment: Given that "like many of the same things" and also "there are many things which neither friend likes" I guess that each one of them has a different likeness property, that sometimes differs and sometimes agrees. Is this the case?

Comment: @gustavovelascoh Yes, Abraham likes things of one type, Levi likes things of another (related) type, some things are both at once, and some (most) things are neither.

Comment: To perhaps further clarify, all examples in the main puzzle are liked *only* by the person mentioned. (Hint 1 lists some items that are liked by *both* A and L.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Abraham and Levi's preferences are determined by...

> .. the suffixes which can be appended to the base words to turn them into adjectives. 
>  Abraham prefers "-ic" while Levi prefers "-ical". (Abrahamic and Levitical comes to mind)

Abraham's list

> artisitic, asymptotic, dramatic, homeopathic, iconoclastic, ironic, logarithmic, parabolic, periodic, sarcastic, scientific

Levi's list

> astrological, chemical, ecological, farcical, ideological, mathematical, parenthetical, technological, theatrical, satirical, zoological

and their shared words

> historic / historical, geographic / geographical, electric / electrical

Comment: rot13(qenzgvpny)? and rot13(periodical).

Comment: @Abbas nice catch! i think it's a miss on the OP's part though and should be on the shared list as well

Comment: OH MY LIFE. How did I end up down such a long blind alley?! This must surely be the answer! +1 :) Think I got blinded by the uncanny pattern in my Abraham answer which must surely be just a very odd coincidence... I clearly need a holiday!

Comment: @greysaff could be, just like I missed rot13() on periodical.

Comment: @Stiv you must really love Pokemon because us casual gamers would never have noticed that pattern. :D Anyways, have a good weekend, mate!

Comment: Used to be a bit of an obsession tbh!  No wonder I ended up overthinking this one so badly... Cheers, you too!

Comment: @Abbas https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dramatic%2Cdramatical&year_start=1950. As for periodical, it's a perfectly good noun, but the rule requires specifically adjectives.

Comment: @greysaff, excellent work! Did you look at the other 2 hints? I'd be curious if you are able to explain hint 3...

Comment: @thecommexokid it's a nice tool you showed me on the graph. Periodical I'm sure is an adjective [on merriam](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/periodical). As for the first one admittedly it is not there.

Comment: @thecommexokid in fact it is there [Merriam](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dramatical).

Comment: @Abbas Re:qenzgvpny, if Merriam marks it "archaic" and the definition is a simple redirect—plus Google N-grams viewer shows it indistinguishable from 0% usage—I'm happy to stand by that as an unattested word. I admit you may have a point on the adjective sense of periodical; I had never heard it other than as a noun so I did not think to check it in N-grams, but it appears to be attested at about 20% the prevalence of periodic. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=periodic%2Cperiodical_ADJ&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950

Comment: Given the inherent subjectivity of determining what is or is not a valid English word, I'm considering myself lucky to only be in an argument about 1 or 2 of these. It was a known risk in generating this puzzle and honestly I had feared worse :).

Comment: @thecommexokid I had no idea what archaic meant next to the word. Granted the usage has dropped (having looked it up) over the last century or two. That does not exclude the word to stop being. However I concede given the fact the word-usage has dropped for such a long time it maybe considered not a word in a puzzle.

Comment: I only picked it up because I've been using the word a lot and I mean a lot. So I guess for me it is still alive, not for the world I guess!

Comment: And that's why LEVI alphabetized the list!

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer**

Since Abraham's name

> begins with **ABRA**, the name of a Pokémon

I wondered whether he might like words which

> contain a 3-letter sequence which begins the name of a Pokémon.

Considering the examples above:

> **DRA**MA = **DRA**tini,
>  **ART** = **ART**icuno,
>  ICO**NOC**LAST = **NOC**towl,
>  HO**MEO**PATH = **MEO**wth,
>  **PER**IODS = **PER**sian,
>  IR**ONY** = **ONY**x (although 'Onix' is the correct spelling),
>  S**ARC**ASM = **ARC**anine,
>  **SCI**ENCE = **SCI**zor,
>  **PAR**ABOLAS = **PAR**as,
>  LOG**ARI**THMS = **ARI**ados,
>  ASYMP**TOT**ES = **TOT**odile.

And from the hints:

> HIS**TOR**Y = **TOR**chic,
>  **GEO** *GRA*PHY = **GEO**dude (or *GRA*veler),
>  **ELE**CTRICITY = **ELE**ctabuzz,
>  **MAG**NETISM = **MAG**neton,
>  **NUM**E*RAL*S = **NUM**el (or *RAL*ts),
>  CY**CLE**S = **CLE**fairy,
>  **GRA**PHS = **GRA**veler,
>  ANGEL**S AN**D DEMONS = **SAN**dslash,
>  **DON** QUIXOTE = **DON**phan,
>  SOC**RAT**ES = **RAT**tata,
>  P**LAT**O = **LAT**ias,
>  **HOR**ROR = **HOR**sea.
>  (Although I cannot make this work for POETRY or SAPPHO...)

However, this logic does not explain why

> it is Levi, and not Abraham, who likes F**ARC**E and **PAR**entheses (unless the fourth letter is also important).

I have also toyed with the idea that Levi might like words which contain

> 3-letter sequences from books of the Bible.

Since

> his name begins **LEVI**ticus, the third book of the Old Testament.

I can make this work for several...

> e.g. **THE**ATER and PAREN**THE**SES as in **THE**ssalonians,
>  **MAT**H as in **MAT**thew,
>  E**COL**OGY as in **COL**ossians,
>  **NUM**ERALS as in **NUM**bers,
>  BIOGRA**PHI**ES as in **PHI**lippians,
>  and even T**HE B**IBLE itself, as in **HEB**rews...

but not for all. More work required, but this partial solution may prove helpful to some if any of it is at all close to being correct!

Comment: My jaw dropped when I saw your Abraham list, what a totally surprising coincidence!

Answer (score 1):

Guided by hint 1 and 3 and based on the comments, I think it is related with:

> - The adjective form of the nouns presented (-ic vs -ical).
>
>   - Abraham has preference for **-ic** form while Levi prefers **-ical**
>
>   - Both agree when valid words exist in **-ic** and **-ical** form.
>
>   - I Applied the rules explained in [this site](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Commonly-Confused-Suffixes-ic-vs-ical.htm) and almost all the words match to this guess.
>
>  However, as I am not a native speaker I am not sure all of them are strictly valid just in one of the forms
>
>   - Regarding the hint 3, I guess they could be classified as  Frozen because of **-ic**-> ICE and Julian because **-ical**-> Calendar App...

Comment: Impressive to solve as a non-native English speaker, especially since I was using my own intuitions (plus some checks on the Google N-grams viewer) to determine what was and was not a "real" English word, rather than any one definitive arbiter. Some of the commenters in @greysaff's answer have argued that a few of my choices should be both lists, but that is to be expected since not every dialect will necessarily agree on which variations are and aren't legal.

Comment: PS: That particular webpage was actually one of the sources I used to find words to use in this puzzle.

Comment: Regarding Hint 3, you have the right words. The exact form of the pun is that Abraham's words rot13(ner *vp*-l) and Levi's words rot13(ner *pny*-raqref).

Comment: (This is very similar to the accepted answer. As a general suggestion: if you're posting an answer that's largely the same as an existing one, acknowledge the prior answer and indicate how yours differs, improves upon, or adds relevant detail to the answer already provided. That way there's no confusion about whether or not you just didn't see the earlier answer. And, of course, if you can't really explain in that manner why your answer is not in essence a simple duplicate, that's probably a good sign that your answer isn't adding anything to what's already been said, and shouldn't be posted.)

Comment: The case is that I didn't see any of the answers and not all the hints given by the OP. I just wanted the feedback from the OP on my conclusions. I only would see the hidden answers once I have decided to give up on solving the puzzle by my own.

Comment: @thecommexokid Regarding hint three: rot13(tebna)